# Calculating integral using cauchy integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis

Calculate 
$$\int_\gamma \frac{1+\sin(z)}{z} dz$$

where $\gamma$ is the circle of centre 0 and radius $\log(\sqrt2)$ oriented counter clockwise.

Well there is a singularity at 0. The fact that the radius is $\log(\sqrt2)$ has no real relevance as this function fails to be analytic at any circle centered at 0.

I used the Cauchy integral formula to calculate the integral and got $2\pi i$. Does that look correct?

Comment: yes your are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\int_\gamma \frac 1 z\,dz + \int_\gamma\frac {\sin z}{z}\,dz.
$$
The second integral is zero because the singularity at $z=0$ is removable.  You can see that by noticing that the power series for $\sin z$ has no constant term, so you can divide the whole thing by $z$ without getting a $1/z$ term.